# You get to choose any two non-zero vectors $v ∈ \mathbb{R}^3$ and $u∈\mathbb{R}^3$. How can I find an equation for a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find the equation of the plane or the line that is spanned by the vectors $u$ and $v$.

I just don't understand what the question means when they ask me to find the equation.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047486/show-in-parametric-form-plane-in-r3/1047505#1047505).

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what the equation of a plane is? To find the Cartesian equation of a plane, you need a point on the plane and a normal vector. If you are given two vectors in the plane, you can take their cross product to find a normal vector. Then you choose any point on any of the vectors in the plane as your point in the plane, and you can easily find the Cartesian equation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29#Point-normal_form_and_general_form_of_the_equation_of_a_plane

Answer (score 0):

Hint #1: the vectors of this plane are exactly the same vectors, who are perpendicular to $u\times v$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $u\times v=(a,b,c)$ then the points $(x,y,z)$ in the plane will satisfy
$$ax+by+cz=0.$$
That's because $(x,y,z)$ must be perpendicular to the direction $u\times v$.